# How can I change the text color of selected list items in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

How can I change the text color of selected list items in SwiftUI? And can I do this dynamically so that if is always a contrasting color to the selected row's background color?

[image: Poor contrast]

```swift
var itemList: some View {
    List{
        ForEach(items, id: \.self, selection: $selectedItem) { item in
             NavigationLink(
                 destination: ItemDetail(item: item)
             ) {
                 ItemRow(item: item)
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be variants but in general you have to pass somehow selection into view with row text and apply foreground color conditionally, like

```
     NavigationLink(
         destination: ItemDetail(item: item)
     ) {
         ItemRow(item: item, selected: item == selectedItem)
     }
```

and in `ItemRow`

```
    Text(item.title)
        .foregroundColor(selected ? .blue : .labelColor)
```

*Note: instead of `.blue` you can set your custom color created in color assets with light/dark mode variants, so selection be differently colored in those modes.*